# Can I capture which templates have been used/not used during an XSL transformation?

Tags: python, xslt, lxml, libxslt

Is it possible to log/capture which XSL templates are used and/or not used during an XML transform using `lxml`? I'm looking to report on and prune unused templates to reduce "technical debt".

Comment: Use unittests and prune based on test failures? If the tests fail, the template was being used?

Answer (score 0):

`lxml`'s transform methods allow you to profile a transformation, and obtain the results as an XML document which shows how many times a pattern/mode/named-template was used. It should be possible to then perform an XPath across the XSL files to obtain all the comparative patterns/modes/named-templates and compare the two lists to see which templates are most/least used.